# Using elements of the column to calculate profitability

Tags: r

I want to calculate the logarithmic profitabilities of a stock asset. The formula for this calculation is:

> ln(Row t+1/row t)

and I want to do this in R. Is it possible?

This is a dirt example of the concept. I hope all you understand it

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the steps you tried.

Comment: To answer your question: it sure is possible in R but please, as noted by others, share some minimal reprodicible example

Comment: `log(df$price[-1] / df$price[-nrow(df)])`

Comment: Thanks for your help, mates!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a very basic solution in base R using a for loop:

```
Date <- c("01-01-2022", "01-02-2022", "01-03-2022")
Date <- as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
Price <- c(2, 3, 5)

df <- data.frame(Date, Price)
df$Profitablity <- rep(NA, nrow(df))

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df$Profitablity[i] <- log(df$Price[i]/df$Price[i-1]) 
}

df

        Date Price Profitablity
1 2022-01-01     2           NA
2 2022-02-01     3    0.4054651
3 2022-03-01     5    0.5108256
```

Comment: You are awesome!